# How to get rid of the game bar in windows 10 when the corresponding option does NOT appear in the control panel?

Tags: windows, windows-10, xbox-game-dvr

I'm a software developper, and my company gave me a Laptop for my work.

The other day, i wanted to receive feedback from a collegue about stuff i was working on. I needed to record my screen to show what i wanted to show, and i used the windows+g shortcut in order to do so.

Since then, **each time i launch a program (firefox for example), an annoying sliding pop-up reminds me that i can use the game bar to take screenshots and record my gameplay.**
(But i don't want to record anything anymore, especially considering how fast firefox's gameplay gets boring.)

---

I used google in order to see what i could do about this. And google answered me :" find the option in the control panel that allows you to disable all game related fonctions". i.e : the xbox option. (Or the one with the x-box logo, at least.)

Problem is, as you can see in this (french) screenshot, **the gaming/xbox option is nowhere to be found.**

[image: Best screenshot ever taken in the last minute]

I have admin rights on this machine, and i can edit the register if necessary. What can i do about this?

Comment: Check if the Gaming option is hidden by group policy or registry. See [here](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/configure-windows-10-settings-visibility-hide-select-settings).

Comment: @Biswapriyo thank you! This helped me to solve my problem. Back to work, i guess. :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Biswapriyo comment, i was able to solve my problem.

I just went to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer** in regedit, and edited the **SettingsPageVisibility** key in order to let me have the options i needed in the control panel.

The old value was hiding a lot of settings, so i made a back-up just in case (file->export) before removing everything xbox/gaming related from said value, and it worked. :)

More info here : https://www.thewindowsclub.com/configure-windows-10-settings-visibility-hide-select-settings